# Push Notification Crashes when i try ti click on when is not running in background Swift 4 ios 13

Tags: firebase, swift3, push-notification

I implemented Firebase to my iOS application.

I am getting notification but when I am clicking on the it takes me to the concerned VC when application is running

My Code is as below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    //Mark: FCM
    FirebaseApp.configure()//for google analytics too

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "Bubble")

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    print("222222222")

    let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "launchedBefore")
    if launchedBefore {
        //print("Not first launch.")
        //Check if already login
        if let token = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "token_key") {
            if token != ""{
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                let navigationController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LaunchVC") as? LaunchViewController
                navigationController.pushViewController(destinationController!, animated: false)
            }
        }
    } else {
        //print("First launch, setting UserDefault.")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "launchedBefore")
        // Mark : delete the token on first launch
       // KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "token_key")
        //KeychainWrapper.standard.removeObject(forKey: "ContactId")
    }

    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    print("33333333")

    return true
}
```

But When i kill my application from background and the recieve a push notification and I click on the notification.

IT CRASHES.......!

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    // TODO: Handle data of notification
    // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
    //Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
    print("44444444")

    let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let navigationController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as? NotificationViewController
    navigationController.pushViewController(destinationController!, animated: false)

    if let messageID = userInfo["aps"] {
        print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
    }
    print("555555555555")

}

func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let navigationController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as? NotificationViewController
    navigationController.pushViewController(destinationController!, animated: false)
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    print("8888888")
}
```

I don't know where i am getting wrong , I have tried possible solution as:
1. Changing the root view controller
2. Instance of a window

One more method..

```
func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
    let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let navigationController = appDelegate.window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let destinationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NotificationVC") as? NotificationViewController
    navigationController.pushViewController(destinationController!, animated: false)
}
```

Not able to get through, Can anybody share..!

thanks in advance..